# Can't understand the working of uniform_filter1d() function (imported from scipy.ndimage.filters)

Tags: python, scipy

I read the scipy docs for the function here : [scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d.html). However, when I tried using it, I couldn't wrap around my head on it's working. I read the docs, ran the example over there in the Python Shell, used my own example but still no progress.
For eg:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter1d
>>> uniform_filter1d([2, 8, 0, 4, 1, 9, 9, 0], size=3)
array([4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 6, 6, 3])
>>> uniform_filter1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], size=3)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7])
```

When I saw the output of the second array, it felt like the function retained most of the array's elements. However in the second example it felt like barring 4 & 1 all the other elements in the output array were completely new.

Thus I would like you to help me understand the working and the use of this function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What this filter does is, according to size, to take the arithmetic average of each pixel with its neighbor. Size is the size of the sub-array to calculate arithmetic average. The standard for pixels without enough neighbors is to reflect. Let us go its process:

```
uniform_filter1d([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=3)

[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 0, Reflect 1 : [1,1,2] -> average: 4/3 = 1
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 1, [1,2,3] -> average: 6/3 = 2
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 2, [2,3,4] -> average: 9/3 = 3
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 3, [3,4,5] -> average: 12/3 = 4
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 4, [4,5,6] -> average: 15/3 = 5
[1,2,3,4,5,6] # index 5, Reflect 6 : [5,6,6] -> average: 17/3 = 5

Result: [1,2,3,4,5,5]
```

Comment: really great explanation. the documentation for this function is really inadequate and doesn't help. your explanation did the trick for me.

Comment: FYI you can turn this code into a super fast running-sum (aka windowed-sum, aka convolve with a rectangle of that has size-n and magnitude 1) by multiplying the input data by size-n! really useful/helpful.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith thanks for info. but couldn't get windowed-sum working. maybe i am doing something wrong. so, for example if i want to add up `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` then should i run `uniform_filter1d([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18], size=3)`?

Comment: @OzgurBagci uniform_filter1d() does a running mean so you have to adjust for that scaling. and it also has non-intuitive params so for example do (1.) `uniform_filter1d(data*size, size=size, mode='constant', cval=0.0, origin=-(size//2)` (2.) you can test against `np.convolve(data, np.ones(size), mode='valid')`

Comment: it's an important tool because it is about 20-30x faster than `np.convolve()`

Comment: @OzgurBagci are you sure it's supposed to be a running mean? Looking at the source https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_filters.c it doesn't appear that way

Comment: @Fosa to my knowledge, in image processing, uniform filter is used for averaging with constant weight across pixels. unfortunately, i need some time to read that source code but, you can read on uniform filter and the definition will back me. also, you can test with floating point numbers on that function to verify. in that source code, i will carefully check from lines 346 to 364. lastly, before i check the source code, if you find some problem with my answer, any edits are welcome.

Comment: Tx, Ozgur. You helped with the mining of the algorithm. Never the less is helpful to say that the point being calculated is placed in window/2. The filter (mean of the window) is done half the window to the left and the other half to the right of the point. if you have uniform_filter1d([2, 8, 0, 4, 1, 9, 9, 0], size=4) you operate over [8, 2, 2, 8, 0 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 9].
Another interesting beaver is with np.nan. If you have uniform_filter1d([2, 8, 0, 4, np.nan, 9, 9, 0], size=4), you will get all nans after you find the nan independently of the np.nan be in the window or not.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add. If you don't want 4/3 = 1, then convert any of the ```int``` in the array into ```float``` by putting a decimal 0.

Comment: but how does the window work is size is even?

Comment: @will.mendil Just play with it a bit, I don't really remember. If you find out, any edits are welcome.